# Calling a woocommerce function in a twig template twice

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, twig, timber

In my php file I am able to write the following:

```
$product = wc_get_product( $context['post']->ID );
$context['sale_price'] = $product->get_variation_sale_price( 'min', false );
```

and `{{sale_price}}` outputs the sale price in my twig file

***however*** I need to do this on a loop through products. In my twig file I can run the `wc_get_product()` function `{% set product = fn('wc_get_product',post.id) %}`

but how can I then do something like: `product->get_variation_sale_price( 'min', false )`???

So essentially running another function on some output from a previous function.

Thanks!!!

Comment: I think the whole point of a templating engine is to keep logic and data manipulation out of the view or template. You should do this kind of thing before the template. And just loop through the values in your template.

Comment: Yes @ngearing I really need help creating a custom function I think that I can pass in the product id which I will have in the loop. Do you no how to write a function that would do something like: ```$product = wc_get_product( $context['post']->ID ); echo $product->get_variation_sale_price( 'min', false );```?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I figured it out...

In my twig file I call a function `{% set pricefield = function(['StarterSite', 'my_function'], post.ID) %}` and as I am returning an array from the function below I have these two bits of output: `{% if pricefield.sale == 'true' %}<div class="ribbon">Sale</div>{% endif %}` and `{{pricefield.price}}`

In my functions file I have this:

```
function my_function($i) {
        $product = wc_get_product($i);
        if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) :

            $product_variations = $product->get_available_variations();

            #2 Get one variation id of a product
            $variation_product_id = $product_variations [0]['variation_id'];

            #3 Create the product object
            $variation_product = new WC_Product_Variation( $variation_product_id );

            #4 Use the variation product object to get the variation prices
            if ($variation_product->sale_price) :
                return array('sale' => 'true', 'price' => '<del>$' . $variation_product->regular_price . '</del> &nbsp;$' . $product->get_variation_sale_price( 'min', false ));
            else : return array('sale' => 'false', 'price' =>  '$' . $variation_product->regular_price);
            endif;
        else:
            if ($product->sale_price) :
                return array('sale' => 'true', 'price' => '<del>$' . $product->regular_price . '</del> &nbsp;$' . $product->sale_price);
            else : return array('sale' => 'false', 'price' =>  '$' . $product->regular_price);
            endif;
        endif;
    }

    /** This is where you can add your own functions to twig.
     *
     * @param string $twig get extension.
     */
    public function add_to_twig( $twig ) {
        $twig->addExtension( new Twig_Extension_StringLoader() );
        $twig->addFilter( new Twig_SimpleFilter( 'myfoo', array( $this, 'myfoo' ) ) );
        $twig->addFunction( new Timber\Twig_Function( 'my_function', 'my_function' ) );
        return $twig;
    }
```

There ended up being a bit more work as I had to take care of products with variable prices and the discount on those and products with a discount but no variable price etc but ultimately it means no functions in the twig template which is the best result.

Wish I could tag all the stack overflow posts I checked out to get to this but can't find them all. Would get great if this helps someone else!